# Select length vs. options.length

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, select

For a select element, is there any difference between the `length` property and the `options.length` property?

In particular, I'd be interested to know if there's a difference in terms of browser support.

Comment: Can you clarify "difference"? Different in output, execution speed..?

Comment: @RUJordan any difference. I haven't found any so far, and I am wondering why we would need two properties that act the same.

Comment: You should use `.options.length`, which makes the intention clear and is more clean. The `.length` property on the `<select>` itself does only exist because it can act as the options container itself (quirks introduced by IE and standardized with HTML5).

Comment: @Bergi not according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FHTMLSelectElement, which states that select.length formally represents "The number of <option> elements in this select element". Either is fine, and either shows clear intention. Select.length is "the number of option elements in this select element", select.options.length is "the number of elements in the list of options childNodes on the select element". Semantic difference, but functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Bergi are you implying that `options.length` has better browser support than `length`?

Comment: @Christophe: I don't know (and would not care). Every current, decent browser supports both; It might be that early IE/NN did not support `.options.length` and that early other browsers were not IE-compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement there is no functional difference, only a "semantic if you want to get really technical about it" difference:

- `select.length` is formally declared as the number of option elements contained by a select element. It will by spec-definition always have the same value as `select.options.length`, which is:
- `select.options.length` is "the number of elements in the list of options childNodes on the select element". Technical difference, semantically slightly different, but due to how `select.length` has been formalised, for all intents and purposes always the same value.

So the first technically "lives" on the `<select>` element, the second lives on the `options` property of the `<select>` element (which is an HTMLOptionsCollection, not an array!), but the value's always the same and it doesn't really matter which you use. Browsers that implement the spec (see [1] and [2]) always give the correct value for either.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/PR-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20021108/html.html#ID-5933486

[2] http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/PR-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20021108/html.html#HTMLOptionsCollectionwill

Answer (score 3):

Both

> select.length

and

> select.options.length

are supported by all major browsers.

The only difference between them (as far as I know) is

- `select.length` is select property which returns its number of options - that's the definition. In other words `length` in select is a special property of this particular DOM element
- `select.options.length` simply returns the number of elements in `options` collection (the same logic as `document.getElementsByTagName('div').length`)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same definitely I had to find out the hardway trying

There are 3 options defined in the HTML/PHP

Calling a JQUERY function and results are

Before selecting anything in the combobox

```
console.log(select.length);   // 1
console.log(select.options.length); // undefined
```

After selecting something

```
console.log(select.length);   // 3
console.log(select.options.length); // 3
```