# Javascript loop way faster in IE than Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a simple for-loop in a JS file on an old aspx web page:

```
function SaveCurrentFilterDisplay() {
    var currentFilterCode = document.getElementById('curfilt').value;
    var currentFilterList, currentFilterDisplay;
    var i, str;

    if (currentFilterCode != '') {
        currentFilterList = document.getElementById(currentFilterCode);
        currentFilterDisplay = document.getElementById(currentFilterCode + '_display');

        //save the previous filter text names
        //alert(currentFilterCode + ': ' + currentFilterList.length);
        if (currentFilterList.length) {
            //multi-select list
            str = '';
            for (i = 0; i < currentFilterList.length; i++) {
                if (currentFilterList.options[i].selected) {
                    if (str.length > 0) {
                        str = str + ', '
                    }
                    str = str + currentFilterList.options[i].text;
                }
            }
        } else {
            //text field
            str = currentFilterList.value;
        }

        alert('finished looping');
        currentFilterDisplay.value = str;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Sometimes this loop has to loop almost 50,000 times. Others just a few hundred or less.

What is perplexing me is that when the loop has to loop 50,000 times and I run this in Chrome, it takes around 2 minutes. But when I do the exact same thing in IE it takes just a few seconds, sometimes it even seems instantaneous.

I am wondering if there is an explanation having to do with how the Chrome based browsers handle Javascript?

EDIT: And perhaps any suggestions on how to optimize this so that it doesn't take 2 minutes in Chrome?

EDIT 2: I have updated my question to show the entire function. When I step through the function using the Chrome dev tools, all of the statements in the method execute instantly, but when I step over the loop it takes 2 minutes to hit the alert statement, so it *is* the loop that is taking 2 minutes.

Here is some HTML showing what currentFilterList is getting pointed to:

```
<select id="ID" name="adv" multiple="true">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

So as an example, currentFilterCode = "ID". This makes currentFilterList set to the select list above (Much shorter than the real one for obvious reasons).

**Final Edit:** After help from comments I did post my solution to the particular problem I was facing. It is not the best way to go about a similar situation, but it works within the constraints of the application I was working on. I chose the other answer as the solution because it is the way to go for similar situations.

Comment: They're completely different JavaScript implementations, with different optimizations.

Comment: Your code seems wrong: Your loop runs up to `currentFilterList.length`, but you *use* `currentFilterList.options[i]`. The loop should run up to `currentFilterList.options.length` in this case.

Comment: I just tried your loop in the Chrome console. It took a fraction of a second with 50,000 strings each 7 characters long.

Comment: If I had to guess: You run - or measure - different code than what you show here.

Comment: What is `currentFilterList`? Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the slowness?

Comment: @Tomalak I have updated my question to address your comment.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my question to include the entire function that is being called

Comment: @Mr.Spock Thanks, but that doesn't really make sense. What kind of elements is `currentFilterList`? Can you also add the corresponding HTML in a self-contained example so that we can run it ourselves?

Comment: @Bergi, I have added some more for clarity. I could work on creating a whole HTML document for a self contained example later. Thanks for looking at this btw

Comment: @Tomolak according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301712/select-length-vs-options-length there is no difference between currentFilterList.length and currentFilterList.options.length because currentFilterList is pointing to a select element

Comment: @Barmar since it was super fast with just strings, I am wondering if it has to do with the javascript having to go and get the options[i] element from the DOM for each iteration. But IDK if that is how the JS actually works

Comment: What kind of madman creates a dropdown with 50,000 options?

Comment: @Mr.Spock I guess a) you should never have a `<select>` element in your DOM with 50,000 options (how did you even create that? how is the user supposed to interact with it?) and b) Chrome just has a less optimised DOM access than IE. I would suggest trying `const values = for (const o of currentFilterList.options) { if (o.selected) values.push(o.text); } currentFilterDisplay.value = values.join(', ');`, maybe that loop is quicker

Comment: Instead of looping over all options and testing `option[i].selected`, use the `selectedOptions` property. See https://www.techiedelight.com/get-selected-values-multi-select-dropdown-javascript/

Comment: @Bergi in my defense, I am working on a legacy asp website that was built several years ago. I was tasked with fixing the problem of it hanging in Chrome. I did not create the monster select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why are we looping to find the selections when we can do it with a selector? Use map and join to build up a string of the selected values.

```js
document.querySelector("#select1").addEventListener("change", () => {
  const out = [...document.querySelectorAll('#select1 option:checked')].map(x => x.text);
  console.log(out.join(', '));
});



/*
document.querySelector("#select1").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var out = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#select1 option:checked')).map(function(x) { return x.text; });
  console.log(out.join(', '));
});
*/
```

```html
<select id="select1" multiple>
  <option>FOO1</option>
  <option>FOO2</option>
  <option>FOO3</option>
  <option>FOO4</option>
  <option>FOO5</option>
  <option>FOO6</option>
  <option>FOO7</option>
  <option>FOO8</option>
  <option>FOO9</option>
  <option>FOO10</option>
</select>
```

OR with selected Options and map and join

```js
document.querySelector("#select1").addEventListener("change", () => {
  var out = [...document.querySelector('#select1').selectedOptions].map(x => x.text);
  console.log(out.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<select id="select1" multiple>
  <option>FOO1</option>
  <option>FOO2</option>
  <option>FOO3</option>
  <option>FOO4</option>
  <option>FOO5</option>
  <option>FOO6</option>
  <option>FOO7</option>
  <option>FOO8</option>
  <option>FOO9</option>
  <option>FOO10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shout out to everyone who worked with me in the comments as I tried to work around the ugly legacy code I got stuck trying to optimize. Thanks to them, I was led to a solution.

The problem has to do with getting properties from the i<sup>th</sup> option in the giant select in the loop.

I found this excellent article: https://idiallo.com/javascript/minimize-lookups-in-for-loops

Which mentioned several ways to optimize a loop accessing DOM elements like the one I was working with. The author mentions how creating and reassigning variables slows it all down (read the real thing, I don't do it justice). The fix was creating variables outside of the loop and using them. After applying the changes I got the following:

```
function SaveCurrentFilterDisplay() {
    var currentFilterCode = document.getElementById('curfilt').value;
    var currentFilterList, currentFilterDisplay;
    var i = 0, str, numOptions, selectedOptions;

    if (currentFilterCode != '') {
        currentFilterList = document.getElementById(currentFilterCode);
        currentFilterDisplay = document.getElementById(currentFilterCode + '_display');

        selectedOptions = currentFilterList.selectedOptions;

        numOptions = selectedOptions.length;

        if (selectedOptions.length) {
            str = '';
            for (; i < numOptions; i++) {
                if (str.length > 0) {
                    str = str + ', '
                }
                str = str + selectedOptions[i].text;
            }
        } else {
            str = currentFilterList.value;
        }

        currentFilterDisplay.value = str;
    }
}
```

The author mentions that the performance gains will be negligible. However like everyone reading this post, he probably didn't think about looping over a 50,000 option long select list!

This now runs through the 50,000 items in less than a second!

EDIT: Edited to use selectedOptions as mentioned in the comments. This is how I got this old web page working. Obviously it is not *the best* solution, but it works within the constraints the rest of the application puts on me.

Comment: The performance gains are not neglible because you were accessing `.length` on a DOM element, not on a simple array. DOM access is very slow (and barely optimisable) in comparison to native JS objects.

Comment: As @Barmar mentions in the comments, just use [`.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) to let some native code do the filtering for you.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for explaining that to me, I appreciate it